# How to list dependency packages of a LaTeX file on OS X?

Tags: mac

I need to know what packages are used in a LaTeX file. Is there a way to list them? For example, I have a file which uses `tikz-dependency`, how can I find out which packages this package uses?

If there's a fancy OS X way to do it, that's welcome. I have MacTex installed, but I didn't manage to find a tool which does this. (Tex Live Utility lists packages, but not dependencies.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On any system you can add the command `\listfiles` to your document and near the end of the log you will then find a list of files used in that computation.  For example,

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- (1,0) node[rectangle,draw,right] {X};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

writes the following in the log file:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
    tikz.sty    2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)
     pgf.sty    2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)
  pgfrcs.sty    2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2010/03/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.18)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 ***********
```

Note this command only detects files loaded via standard latex file macros, including `\documentclass`, `\usepcakage`, `\include`.  It also works for `\input` if used in the LaTeX way `\input{file}`, but not if used in the plain tex way `\input file`.  It does not list `.aux` files, nor the `.toc` as input by `\tableofcontents`.  There is an internal LaTeX command `\@input` that can load files without placing them on this list.

Answer (score 0):

I am investigating a problem on Linux where I am interested in tracing the full pathnames of resources loaded by my LaTeX processors. My answer is to run under `strace -e trace=open`. The equivalent on macOS is dtruss, I believe.